# Can I use Table or something else instead of While in this case?

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, procedural-programming, table

I have a very long code that take an extremely large amount of time. I have been using the While loop, but with each iteration, it gets slower and slower, so I know there has to be a better way of doing this than using While. I won't post the code since it's too long, but I will post the basic idea of what I need it to do.

```
currentvalue = 50; 
a = 5; 
b = 10; 
table1 = {10, 10, 5, 10, 5}; 
table2 = {10, 10, 5, 10, 5}; 
n = 1; While[n <= 15, rnd = RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]; If[table1[[rnd]] == a, table1[[rnd]] = b, table1[[rnd]] = a]; If[Total[table1] < currentvalue, currentvalue = Total[table1]; table2 = table1, table1 = table2]; Print[{table1, currentvalue}]; n++]
```

So, in this example, I am trying to minimize the sum of the list elements, so I am flipping one element to the other value, and checking if the sum gets smaller, if so, I update table1, and so on. So the idea is, I need to do many iterations, where I use the first conditional to initially update the list table1, and then I use the second conditional to see if I want to accept that update or not. Is there a way I can use Table with something like this so I can have my code run much faster than it is?

**Edit:**
I will include a shortened version of the actual code in case it helps.

```
h = 1/10^2;
p = 1600;
stiffness = {2*10^6, 2*10^6, 2*10^6, 2*10^6};
boundary1 = .25;
boundary2 = boundary1*2;
boundary3 = boundary1*3;
boundary4 = boundary1*4;
a = 8*10^4;
b = 2*10^6;

function := 
 Module[{nsolution1, radialstretch1, thetastretch1, angle1, 
   radialboundary1, thetastretchderivative1, Rderivative1, f1, 
   nsolution2, radialstretch2, thetastretch2, angle2, radialboundary2,
    thetastretchderivative2, Rderivative2, f2, nsolution3, 
   radialstretch3, thetastretch3, angle3, radialboundary3, 
   thetastretchderivative3, Rderivative3, f3, nsolution4, 
   radialstretch4, thetastretch4, angle4, radialboundary4, 
   thetastretchderivative4, Rderivative4, f4, slope1, slope2, slope3, 
   slope4, , values, slopeerror, w1}, 
  nsolution1 = 
   ParametricNDSolve[{lt[r] + r Derivative[1][lt][r] == 
      lr[r] Cos[\[Beta][r]], 
     p r lt[r]* lr[r] Cos[\[Beta][r]] - 
       stiffness[[1]]* 
        h Sin[\[Beta][r]] (lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^2)) - 
       stiffness[[1]]* 
        h r Derivative[1][\[Beta]][
         r] Cos[\[Beta][r]] (lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^2)) - 
       stiffness[[1]]* 
        h r Sin[\[Beta][
          r]] (Derivative[1][lr][
           r] + (3 Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4 lt[
              r]^2) + (2 Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^3)) == 
      0, -p r lr[r] lt[r] Sin[\[Beta][r]] - 
       stiffness[[1]]* 
        h Cos[\[Beta][r]] (lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^2)) + 
       stiffness[[1]]* 
        h r Derivative[1][\[Beta]][
         r] Sin[\[Beta][r]] (lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^2)) - 
       stiffness[[1]]* 
        h r Cos[\[Beta][
          r]] (Derivative[1][lr][
           r] + (3 Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4 lt[
              r]^2) + (2 Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^3)) + 
       stiffness[[1]]* h (lt[r] - 1/(lr[r]^2 lt[r]^3)) == 0, 
     lt[0.001] == w1, lr[0.001] == w1, \[Beta][0.001] == 0.001}, {lr, 
     lt, \[Beta]}, {r, 0.001, boundary1}, {w1}];
  radialstretch1[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] := 
   lr[v1][v2] /. nsolution1; 
  thetastretch1[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] = 
   lt[v1][v2] /. nsolution1; 
  angle1[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] = \[Beta][v1][v2] /. nsolution1;
  radialboundary1[v1_?NumericQ, 
    v2_?NumericQ] := (1/(\[Sqrt]2)) (\[Sqrt]((stiffness[[
            1]]*(radialstretch1[v1, v2]^2 - 
             1/(radialstretch1[v1, v2]^2 thetastretch1[v1, v2]^2)))/
         stiffness[[
          2]] + (\[Sqrt]((stiffness[[1]] - 
               radialstretch1[v1, v2]^4 thetastretch1[v1, 
                 v2]^2 stiffness[[1]])^2 + 
             4 radialstretch1[v1, v2]^4 thetastretch1[v1, 
               v2]^2 (stiffness[[2]])^2))/(radialstretch1[v1, 
            v2]^2 thetastretch1[v1, v2]^2 stiffness[[2]])));
  thetastretchderivative1[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] := \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\((\(lt[v1]\)[t] /.  
       nsolution1)\)\) /. t -> v2;
  Rderivative1[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] := 
   thetastretch1[v1, v2] + v2* thetastretchderivative1[v1, v2];
  f1[v1_?NumericQ, 
    v2_?NumericQ] := -\[Sqrt](radialstretch1[v1, v2]^2 - 
       Rderivative1[v1, v2]^2);
  slope1[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] := 
   1/Rderivative1[v1, v2]/f1[v1, v2];
  
  nsolution2 = 
   ParametricNDSolve[{lt[r] + r Derivative[1][lt][r] == 
      lr[r] Cos[\[Beta][r]], 
     p r lt[r] lr[r] Cos[\[Beta][r]] - 
       stiffness[[2]]* 
        h Sin[\[Beta][r]] (lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^2)) - 
       stiffness[[2]]* 
        h r Derivative[1][\[Beta]][
         r] Cos[\[Beta][r]] (lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^2)) - 
       stiffness[[2]]* 
        h r Sin[\[Beta][
          r]] (Derivative[1][lr][
           r] + (3 Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4 lt[
              r]^2) + (2 Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^3)) == 
      0, -p r lr[r] lt[r] Sin[\[Beta][r]] - 
       stiffness[[2]]* 
        h Cos[\[Beta][r]] (lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^2)) + 
       stiffness[[2]]* 
        h r Derivative[1][\[Beta]][
         r] Sin[\[Beta][r]] (lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^2)) - 
       stiffness[[2]]* 
        h r Cos[\[Beta][
          r]] (Derivative[1][lr][
           r] + (3 Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4 lt[
              r]^2) + (2 Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^3)) + 
       stiffness[[2]]* h (lt[r] - 1/(lr[r]^2 lt[r]^3)) == 0, 
     lr[boundary1] == radialboundary1[w1, boundary1], 
     lt[boundary1] == 
      thetastretch1[w1, boundary1], \[Beta][boundary1] == 
      angle1[w1, boundary1]}, {lr, lt, \[Beta]}, {r, boundary1, 
     boundary2}, {w1}];
  radialstretch2[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] := 
   lr[v1][v2] /. nsolution2; 
  thetastretch2[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] = 
   lt[v1][v2] /. nsolution2; 
  angle2[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] = \[Beta][v1][v2] /. nsolution2;
  radialboundary2[v1_?NumericQ, 
    v2_?NumericQ] := (1/(\[Sqrt]2)) (\[Sqrt]((stiffness[[
            2]]*(radialstretch2[v1, v2]^2 - 
             1/(radialstretch2[v1, v2]^2 thetastretch2[v1, v2]^2)))/
         stiffness[[
          3]] + (\[Sqrt]((stiffness[[2]] - 
               radialstretch2[v1, v2]^4 thetastretch2[v1, 
                 v2]^2 stiffness[[2]])^2 + 
             4 radialstretch2[v1, v2]^4 thetastretch2[v1, 
               v2]^2 (stiffness[[3]])^2))/(radialstretch2[v1, 
            v2]^2 thetastretch2[v1, v2]^2 stiffness[[3]])));
  thetastretchderivative2[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] := \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\((\(lt[v1]\)[t] /.  
       nsolution2)\)\) /. t -> v2;
  Rderivative2[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] := 
   thetastretch2[v1, v2] + v2* thetastretchderivative2[v1, v2];
  f2[v1_?NumericQ, 
    v2_?NumericQ] := -\[Sqrt](radialstretch2[v1, v2]^2 - 
       Rderivative2[v1, v2]^2);
  slope2[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] := 
   1/Rderivative2[v1, v2]/f2[v1, v2];
  nsolution3 = 
   ParametricNDSolve[{lt[r] + r Derivative[1][lt][r] == 
      lr[r] Cos[\[Beta][r]], 
     p r lt[r] lr[r] Cos[\[Beta][r]] - 
       stiffness[[3]]* 
        h Sin[\[Beta][r]] (lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^2)) - 
       stiffness[[3]]* 
        h r Derivative[1][\[Beta]][
         r] Cos[\[Beta][r]] (lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^2)) - 
       stiffness[[3]]* 
        h r Sin[\[Beta][
          r]] (Derivative[1][lr][
           r] + (3 Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4 lt[
              r]^2) + (2 Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^3)) == 
      0, -p r lr[r] lt[r] Sin[\[Beta][r]] - 
       stiffness[[3]]* 
        h Cos[\[Beta][r]] (lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^2)) + 
       stiffness[[3]]* 
        h r Derivative[1][\[Beta]][
         r] Sin[\[Beta][r]] (lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^2)) - 
       stiffness[[3]]* 
        h r Cos[\[Beta][
          r]] (Derivative[1][lr][
           r] + (3 Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4 lt[
              r]^2) + (2 Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^3)) + 
       stiffness[[3]]* h (lt[r] - 1/(lr[r]^2 lt[r]^3)) == 0, 
     lr[boundary2] == radialboundary2[w1, boundary2], 
     lt[boundary2] == 
      thetastretch2[w1, boundary2], \[Beta][boundary2] == 
      angle2[w1, boundary2]}, {lr, lt, \[Beta]}, {r, boundary2, 
     boundary3}, {w1}];
  radialstretch3[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] := 
   lr[v1][v2] /. nsolution3; 
  thetastretch3[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] = 
   lt[v1][v2] /. nsolution3; 
  angle3[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] = \[Beta][v1][v2] /. nsolution3;
  radialboundary3[v1_?NumericQ, 
    v2_?NumericQ] := (1/(\[Sqrt]2)) (\[Sqrt]((stiffness[[
            3]]*(radialstretch3[v1, v2]^2 - 
             1/(radialstretch3[v1, v2]^2 thetastretch3[v1, v2]^2)))/
         stiffness[[
          4]] + (\[Sqrt]((stiffness[[3]] - 
               radialstretch3[v1, v2]^4 thetastretch3[v1, 
                 v2]^2 stiffness[[3]])^2 + 
             4 radialstretch3[v1, v2]^4 thetastretch3[v1, 
               v2]^2 (stiffness[[4]])^2))/(radialstretch3[v1, 
            v2]^2 thetastretch3[v1, v2]^2 stiffness[[4]])));
  thetastretchderivative3[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] := \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\((\(lt[v1]\)[t] /.  
       nsolution3)\)\) /. t -> v2;
  Rderivative3[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] := 
   thetastretch3[v1, v2] + v2* thetastretchderivative3[v1, v2];
  f3[v1_?NumericQ, 
    v2_?NumericQ] := -\[Sqrt](radialstretch3[v1, v2]^2 - 
       Rderivative3[v1, v2]^2);
  slope3[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] := 
   1/Rderivative3[v1, v2]/f3[v1, v2];
  nsolution4 = 
   ParametricNDSolve[{lt[r] + r Derivative[1][lt][r] == 
      lr[r] Cos[\[Beta][r]], 
     p r lt[r] lr[r] Cos[\[Beta][r]] - 
       stiffness[[4]]* 
        h Sin[\[Beta][r]] (lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^2)) - 
       stiffness[[4]]* 
        h r Derivative[1][\[Beta]][
         r] Cos[\[Beta][r]] (lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^2)) - 
       stiffness[[4]]* 
        h r Sin[\[Beta][
          r]] (Derivative[1][lr][
           r] + (3 Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4 lt[
              r]^2) + (2 Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^3)) == 
      0, -p r lr[r] lt[r] Sin[\[Beta][r]] - 
       stiffness[[4]]* 
        h Cos[\[Beta][r]] (lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^2)) + 
       stiffness[[4]]* 
        h r Derivative[1][\[Beta]][
         r] Sin[\[Beta][r]] (lr[r] - 1/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^2)) - 
       stiffness[[4]]* 
        h r Cos[\[Beta][
          r]] (Derivative[1][lr][
           r] + (3 Derivative[1][lr][r])/(lr[r]^4 lt[
              r]^2) + (2 Derivative[1][lt][r])/(lr[r]^3 lt[r]^3)) + 
       stiffness[[4]]* h (lt[r] - 1/(lr[r]^2 lt[r]^3)) == 0, 
     lr[boundary3] == radialboundary3[w1, boundary3], 
     lt[boundary3] == 
      thetastretch3[w1, boundary3], \[Beta][boundary3] == 
      angle3[w1, boundary3]}, {lr, lt, \[Beta]}, {r, boundary3, 
     boundary4}, {w1}];
  radialstretch4[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] := 
   lr[v1][v2] /. nsolution4; 
  thetastretch4[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] = 
   lt[v1][v2] /. nsolution4; 
  angle4[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] = \[Beta][v1][v2] /. nsolution4;
  thetastretchderivative4[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] := \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\((\(lt[v1]\)[t] /.  
       nsolution4)\)\) /. t -> v2;
  Rderivative4[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] := 
   thetastretch4[v1, v2] + v2* thetastretchderivative4[v1, v2];
  f4[v1_?NumericQ, 
    v2_?NumericQ] := -\[Sqrt](radialstretch4[v1, v2]^2 - 
       Rderivative4[v1, v2]^2);
  slope4[v1_?NumericQ, v2_?NumericQ] := 
   1/Rderivative4[v1, v2]/f4[v1, v2];
  values = Table[x, {x, 0.05, 1, 0.05}];
  slopeerror[
    v1_?NumericQ] := (1/
      Length[values])*(Sum[(slope1[v1, values[[i]]] + 
         2*values[[i]]*Exp[-values[[i]]^2])^2, {i, 1, 5}] + 
      Sum[(slope2[v1, values[[i]]] + 
         2*values[[i]]*Exp[-values[[i]]^2])^2, {i, 5, 10}] + 
      Sum[(slope3[v1, values[[i]]] + 
         2*values[[i]]*Exp[-values[[i]]^2])^2, {i, 10, 15}] + 
      Sum[(slope4[v1, values[[i]]] + 
         2*values[[i]]*Exp[-values[[i]]^2])^2, {i, 15, 20}]);
  
  
  {thetastretch4, slopeerror}]

current = 200;
stiffness0 = {8*10^4, 2*10^6, 8*10^4, 2*10^6, 8*10^4, 2*10^6, 8*10^4, 
   2*10^6, 8*10^4, 2*10^6, 8*10^4};

Quiet[Monitor[n = 1; 
  While[n < 25, 
   rnd = RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}]; 
   If[stiffness[[rnd]] == a, stiffness[[rnd]] = b, 
    stiffness[[rnd]] = a];
   listofvalues = 
    Quiet[Select[
      Table[{x, 
        function[[1]][x, 1]}, {x, {1.001, 1.002, 1.003, 1.004, 1.005, 
         1.0055, 1.006, 1.007, 1.008, 1.009, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 
         1.05, 1.06, 1.07, 1.08, 1.09, 1.1, 1.11, 1.12, 1.13, 1.14, 
         1.15, 1.16, 1.17, 1.18, 1.2, 1.22, 1.24, 1.26, 1.28, 1.3, 
         1.32, 1.34, 1.36, 1.38, 1.4}}], Abs[#[[2]]] < 5 &]];
   root = 
    w1 /. FindRoot[
      function[[1]][w1, 1] == 1, {w1, listofvalues[[1, 1]], 
       listofvalues[[3, 1]]}]; 
   If[function[[2]][root] < current, current = function[[2]][root]; 
    stiffness0 = stiffness; 
    Print[function[[2]][root], stiffness, root], 
    stiffness = stiffness0;]; n++]; n, n]]
```

So, I have these differential equations that I defined inside of Module in what I called function, and I need them solved for different conditions many times over. That is why I am using that while loop, where I change the list called stiffness, and then redo the equations to see if I am getting closer to a desired result. Each time the stiffness list is changed, "function" gives a different result for the differential equations, so it has to be ran again inside the loop.

Comment: I think you could get better answers if you would describe the problem you are attempting to solve because there is probably a significantly better abstraction available in Mathematica for it than `While` loops or brute-force `Table`s. I believe current code in the question doesn't sufficiently expose the nature of the problem to write informative answers.

Comment: I will edit the question to include the code as well.

Comment: Even better if you can describe the problem you're trying to solve; for instance "find a subset of size 5 with a minimal sum." If the problem itself is well-formed there tend to be good domain-specific tools available in Mathematica...

Comment: I've updated the question with the edit and a short explanation of the problem itself. But, it is a bit hard to look at..

Comment: So, your problem is essentially that you want to find a local minimum of a non-linear (slow) function which takes an effectively binary-valued input vector, and to perform this iterative search by conditionally flipping individual entries on the vector on each search step?

Comment: Your question has a very simple answer; The sum gets smaller every time you replace a list element by a smaller one. Therefore, the smallest sum is achieved when all list elements have the smallest possible value. But I guess this is not the whole truth and there are complications.

Comment: @DanielHuber I believe `Total` is a bit unfortunate choice for an arbitrary function in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something resembling your problem in a functional programming form: a complicated function `f` which takes a vector as input, `ab` listing two possible values of each vector item, and a `Nest`ed search which flips individual vector items randomly, attempting to avoid repeated calculations of `f`. I can't say anything about efficiency, but I assume most of the time in the real-world case would be spent inside `f` anyway...

```
Module[
 {ab, f},
 (* Alternative values on each vector item. *)
 ab = {1, Sqrt[2]};
 (* A complicated function we want to minimize. *)
 f[v_] := Sum[Sin[Prime[i] v[[i]]], {i, Length[v]}] // N;
 Nest[
   (* Search iteration step. *)
   Apply[Function[{v, best, seen},
     With[
      {vcand =
        (* Find a candidate vector by flipping a random vector entry.
           If vector is already tested, try again until a new one
           is found, or Length[v] tries have been made. *)
        NestWhile[
         ReplaceAt[v, {1 -> 2, 2 -> 1}, RandomInteger[Length[v]]] &,
         {},
         # == {} || MemberQ[seen, #] &,
         1, Length[v]]},
      With[{val = f[ab[[vcand]]]},
       If[val <= best,
        (* If value was improved pass new candidate to
           the next iteration. *)
        {vcand, Echo[val], Append[seen, vcand]},
        {v, best, Append[seen, vcand]}]]]]],
   (* Start with random vector, infinite best value and
      no vectors seen.*)
   {RandomInteger[{1, 2}, {10}], Infinity, {}},
   (* 100 iterations *)
   100] //
  (* Assign ab values to the found result. *)
  ab[[First[#]]] &]

(* 
-2.38285

-4.1252

-5.27623

-5.76921

-5.76921

-5.76921

-5.76921

-5.76921

-5.76921

-5.76921

-5.76921

-5.76921
*)

(* {Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2], 1, Sqrt[2], 1, Sqrt[2], 1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

The minimum in this case converged to the real minimum:

```
Sum[Sin[Prime[i] #[[i]]], {i, Length[#]}] & /@ 
   Tuples[{1, Sqrt[2]}, 10] // Min // N

(* -5.76921 *)
```

Comment: I haven’t had the chance to try it in my problem, but it seems like this is exactly what I was asking for. Thank you!